# Is anyone trying to compile demo under tensorflow Lite in windows

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I want to run demo(master/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/micro_speech) in a CEVA dsp with Windows 10.
I know it TFLite should be run in linux.

I work with DSP V18 toolbox, this can provide C++11 compilation environment.
But,

It's hard to compile successfully.

1. Relative path cannot be used for header file.
2. Some file is not in IDE, like pthread.h/types.h/...

Is there someone compilate TFLite demo in Windows 10?

Comment: This post might help your case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63503242/11843861

Comment: @Jae sung Chung Thanks，using linux env in windows maybe the only way for it.